# Xcode appears to be modifying paths inside bash scripts during run script build phase

Tags: xcode, shell

I have a simple script that looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -eux

install_folder="${HOME}/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles"
mkdir -p "${install_folder}"

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
  echo "Unable to create destination directory: ${install_folder}"
  exit 1
fi
```

If I run this script from the command line by doing `./my_script.sh` everything works as expected. Things go wrong though when I call from Xcode as part of a run script build phase. I currently call it by having `"${SRCROOT}/path/to/my_script.sh"` in the run script build phase, but the same issue occurs even if I copy and paste the code above in directly.

So what's the issue? Well, it seems Xcode is causing the wrong folder to be created. When I run from the command line, I get a folder named `Provisioning Profiles` inside `~/Library/MobileDevice/` as expected. When I run from Xcode, the folder is named `Provisioning\ Profiles` (that `\` is literally part of the name).

But it gets weirder. If I change the `mkdir` line to `mkdir -p $install_folder` then I'd expect to get a folder called `Provisioning` inside the `MobileDevice` folder and a folder called `Profiles` wherever I ran the command. That's what happens when I run from the command line. If I run from Xcode however, I get a folder `Profiles` inside `MobileDevice` but I also get a folder called `Provisioning\ Profiles`.

I cannot explain this behavior at all. It seems totally counter to everything I (thought) knew about shell scripts.

How is Xcode influencing this? How do I make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

The trick, as always, was realising that there was more to this than I had considered. Xcode wasn't just running this script in the phase, it was doing it with a list of output files set. It was then creating the path for those after it ran the script. The script was behaving exactly as it should have, it was just the extra stuff which made it appear to be broken.

Lesson learned: Xcode will create a folder for output files if it doesn't exist.